# How can I determine the rule which is used by ANTLR 4 to parse the expression?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to create the Java class that builds AST (Abstract Syntax Tree in my custom class hierarchy) from the parse tree created by ANTLR 4. I am doing this for the language of First Order Logic https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/fol/fol.g4

Specifically I am looking on the rules for `formula`:

```
 formula
   : formula bin_connective formula 
   | NOT formula bin_connective formula
   | NOT formula 
   | FORALL LPAREN variable RPAREN formula 
   | EXISTS LPAREN variable RPAREN formula
   | pred_constant LPAREN term (separator term)* RPAREN
   | term EQUAL term
   ;
```

ANTLR 4 has generated the following class for `formula` which I am presenting here only partially (for the sake of  brevity I am removing the implementation - it is standard and generated by ANTLR 4 and just call some technical methods):

```
public static class FormulaContext extends ParserRuleContext {
        public TerminalNode NOT() { ... }
        public List<FormulaContext> formula() { ... }
        public FormulaContext formula(int i) { ... }
        public Bin_connectiveContext bin_connective() { ... }
        public TerminalNode FORALL() { ... }
        public TerminalNode LPAREN() { ... }
        public VariableContext variable() { ... }
        public TerminalNode RPAREN() { ... }
        public TerminalNode EXISTS() { ... }
        public Pred_constantContext pred_constant() { ... }
        public List<TermContext> term() { ... }
        public TermContext term(int i) { ...  }
        public List<SeparatorContext> separator() { ... }
        public SeparatorContext separator(int i) { ... }
        public TerminalNode EQUAL() { ... }
        public FormulaContext(ParserRuleContext parent, int invokingState) {
            super(parent, invokingState);
        }
        @Override public int getRuleIndex() { return RULE_formula; }
        @Override
        public void enterRule(ParseTreeListener listener) {
            if ( listener instanceof FOLListener ) ((FOLListener)listener).enterFormula(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void exitRule(ParseTreeListener listener) {
            if ( listener instanceof FOLListener ) ((FOLListener)listener).exitFormula(this);
        }
    }
```

So - one can see: if there is rule, that contains `NOT`, then there is method `TerminalNode NOT`, is there are one or more methods that contain one or more formula, then there are 2 methods - one returns `FormulaContext` and other returns `ArrayList<FormulaContext>`. There are no more valuable methods.

Lets assume that I have `FormulaContext` instance and I would like to inspect it further. **What should I do?** My expectation is to know the rule according to which this instance of `FormulaContext` is constructed and then I know which methods (e.t. `formula(0); bin_connective(); formula(1);` for the first rule) can I call and I can call these mehtods safely.

The problem is - that I can not find the methods which determins the rule which is used for the construction is this nonterminal? Of course, I can try to create test method for each rule (e.g. testRule1, testRule2, ...) which calls the mentioned methods and inspects the availability of formula, NOT, bin_connective and all those child terms and then can infere which rule is used and then proceed accordingly further with digesting the instance under consideration.

But is such test methods the right approach? I can not believe that all this is so crude. Besides, such test methods can be generated automatically by ANTLR 4, there is all the information for them, but still - ANTLR has no such feature.

So - what is the best practice to infere the rule for the Non Terminal class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [label your alternatives](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels) using the `#` operator like this:

```
formula
    : formula bin_connective formula #BinaryFormula
    | NOT formula                    #Negation
    | ...
    ;
```

This will create classes `NegationContext` etc. that inherit from `FormulaContext`. So you can tell which alternative was chosen based on which class you get. In visitors and listeners, you can now overload `visitNegation(NegationContext)` etc. to visit that specific type of formula.